# Is this overwatered English Ivy beyond salvation?

Tags: leaves, watering, english-ivy, poison-ivy

This English Ivy has been left outdoor for a week. It rained quite a lot in the past few days and when i rescued it, the leaves were mostly brown. When the plant was kept indoor the foliage was pretty thick, but i had to remove the dead leaves and now the plant looks like this:

[image]
[image]

Is the plant beyond salvation? What can i do to restore the foliage?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Did you harden it off before putting it in full sun?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the roots yet to see if they show signs of root rot? If yes, then you may need to clean off the rotted roots and replant in dry soil. If not then you can just wait until the soil dries out and water very conservatively for a while. Ivies are quite hardy and easy to propagate. If the root rot is too extensive, I’d recommend taking some cutting and propagating.

Comment: I'll try to take a look at the roots. Thank you for the suggestion!